# create javascript array(N) of consecutively smaller integers with the sum of 1000

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, probability, weighted

I am working on a text based roll playing game, and i need to generate an array of N values of probabilities, with each consecutive value being smaller (rarer) than the one before, with the total sum equaling 1000. 1000 is important because elsewhere I have probabilities < 1%.

the array is used by this function to generate a weighted random index: with probability being the array in question

```
function rndProb(probability)
{

    chances = new Array();
    for(var x=0; x<probability.length ; x++)
    {
        for(var y=0; y<probability[x]; y++)
        {
        chances.push(x);
        }
    }
    var px = Math.floor(Math.random() * chances.length+1);
    return chances[px];
}
```

I realize this function is not efficient, but it only needs to run a few times so performance is not important. I need it to be dynamic, so i can change the number of items in the list, but all added equal 1000
ie:

```
var rankProb = [400,310,160,100,25,5];
```

something like

```
function probGen(arrayLength)
{
    for(var i=0;i<arrayLength;i++)
    {
         prob.push(((1000-arrayLength)/arrayLength)+1);
    }
    return prob;
}
```

i just can't figure the formula.

Comment: Maybe post at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ to get help with the algorithm and then translate that into code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the arithmetic sequence 1, 2, ..., N.  The sum of this sequence is S = N*(N+1)/2.  We can easily multiply each member of the sequence by 1000/S to get a sequence that sums to 1000.  (Since you need integers, there will be a remainder, which we can just add onto the largest value.)

In Javascript:

```
function probGen(arrayLength)
{
    var prob = [];
    var sum = arrayLength * (arrayLength + 1) / 2;
    var multiplier = Math.floor(1000 / sum);
    var remainder = 1000 - (sum * multiplier);

    if (sum > 1000) { return null; } // error case

    for (var i = arrayLength ; i > 0 ; i--)
    {
        prob.push(i * multiplier);
    }
    prob[0] += remainder;
    return prob;
}
```

Comment: similar to what i managed to figure... find the multiplier and iterate through, creating evenly spaced probabilities. i posted my answer the same time you did:) marked yours as correct for your time.  thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Made my head hurt though...

```
function generateProbs(arrayLength)
{
    var prob = new Array();
    var diff = 1;
    for(var d=2;d<arrayLength+1;d++)
    {
        diff = diff + d;
    }
    var offset = (1000/diff);

    for(var i=arrayLength;i>0;i--)
    {
        prob.push(Math.round(offset*i));
    }
    return prob;
}
```